# Error while installing C++ Redistributable 2015 on the Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql, .net, windows-server-2012-r2

I need to install MySQL and WorkBench tool on Windows Server 2012 R2. As the prerequesites it needs Visual C++ Redistributable 2015. So I downloaded and tried to install but getting below error:

Log details:

> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:18]i301: Applying execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{BE960C1C-7BAD-3DE6-8B1A-2616FE532845}v14.0.23026\packages\vcRuntimeAdditional_x86\vc_runtimeAdditional_x86.msi, arguments: ' MSIFASTINSTALL="7" NOVSUI="1"'
> [1680:17F8][2019-11-28T23:04:18]i319: Applied execute package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86, result: 0x0, restart: None
> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:18]i325: Registering dependency: {74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e} on package provider: Microsoft.VS.VC_RuntimeAdditionalVSU_x86,v14, package: vcRuntimeAdditional_x86
> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:18]i301: Applying execute package: Windows81_x64, action: Install, path: C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu, arguments: '"C:\Windows\SysNative\wusa.exe" "C:\ProgramData\Package Cache\FC6260C33678BB17FB8B88536C476B4015B7C5E9\packages\Patch\x64\Windows8.1-KB2999226-x64.msu" /quiet /norestart'
> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:19]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
> [1680:17F8][2019-11-28T23:04:19]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to configure per-machine MSU package.
> [1680:17F8][2019-11-28T23:04:19]i319: Applied execute package: Windows81_x64, result: 0x80240017, restart: None
> [1680:17F8][2019-11-28T23:04:19]e000: Error 0x80240017: Failed to execute MSU package.
> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:19]i372: Session end, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart: None, disable resume: No
> [12E4:1754][2019-11-28T23:04:19]i371: Updating session, registration key: SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall{74d0e5db-b326-4dae-a6b2-445b9de1836e}, resume: ARP, restart initiated: No, disable resume: No
> [1680:17F8][2019-11-28T23:04:19]i399: Apply complete, result: 0x80240017, restart: None, ba requested restart:  No

- OS: Windows Server R2
- System Type: 64 bit OS, x64-based processor
- Updated: Yes
- MySQL Version: 5.5
- WorkBench Version: 8.0.18

What could the reason behind this?

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b9cf664b-5c5b-4cf0-9764-26a2ffc3735a/solved-failing-to-install-visual-c-redistributable-for-visual-studio-2015?forum=posready

Comment: @Eldar Yes I downloaded that and trying to install then it shows me an warning that `This update is not applicable for your computer`

Comment: Because that link leads to Windows Embeded download section try downloading from  [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=49063)

Comment: @Eldar The download link is broken - `404 - File or directory not found.`

Comment: Updated with a working link.

Comment: @Eldar Thanks but still getting same error: `This update is not applicable for your computer` I have license product key is that the problem??

Comment: Weird i don't think license will be the problem, try moving your question to server fault.

Comment: @Eldar Added new question on SF! thanks for you time. Actually new to this and trying to setup new server!

Comment: @Eldar Found the solution, it was related to windows update, user from SF suggested to update the OS if there is anything pending!

Comment: Good to know that. Experience saves lives.

Comment: @Eldar Posted answer, might be will help someone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is:

1. Check for Windows Update

   Control Panel > Windows Update
2. Install the all suggested and important updates
3. Restart the computer

Then try to install `vc_redist.[x64 OR x84].exe` again `>` if already install then uninstall and then re-install it.

Then the setup must be successful, then install the Workbench again, will work fine.

Answer (score 2):

I was also getting similar error 0x80240017 while installing VC++ redistributables as pre-requisites for WAMP Server on Windows 2012 Server. I performed following steps to resolve the issue:

1. Install Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2939087):
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42365
2. Install Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB2975061):
   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43531
3. Install KB2919355 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42334),
4. Restart computer
5. Install KB2999226 (https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/download/details.aspx?id=49071)